# odeint: complex and higher precision types

Tags: c++, precision, gsl, floating-point-precision

Could anyone provide me with some assistance in creating a minimum example of using the c++ odeint solver with a vector of complex numbers and if possible with higher precision (boost.multiprecision or libquadmath __float128 , __complex128 say).

There is an example in the docs using a complex scalar http://headmyshoulder.github.com/odeint-v2/doc/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/special_topics.html

and it's mentioned there that :

```
The fact that we have to configure a different algebra is solely due to the fact 
that we use a non-vector state type and not to the usage of complex values.
So for, e.g. vector<  complex<double> >, this would not be required.
```

I tried to modify this with changes like `typedef vector<complex<double>> state_type`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;


typedef vector<complex< double >> state_type;

struct stuart_landau
{
double m_eta;
double m_alpha;

stuart_landau( double eta = 1.0 , double alpha = 1.0 )
: m_eta( eta ) , m_alpha( alpha ) { }

void operator()( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t ) const
{
    const complex<double> I(0.0,1.0);
    dxdt[0] = x[1];
    dxdt[1] = (1.0+m_eta*I)*x[0]-(1.0+m_alpha*I)*x[1];
}
};

 struct streaming_observer
{
std::ostream& m_out;

streaming_observer( std::ostream &out ) : m_out( out ) { }

template< class State >
void operator()( const State &x , double t ) const
{
    m_out << t;
    m_out << "\t" << x[0].real() << "\t" << x[0].imag() ;
    m_out << "\n";*/
}
};

int main( int argc , char **argv )
{
//[ stuart_landau_integration
state_type x(2);
 x[0] = complex< double >( 1.0 , 0.0 );
 x[1] = complex< double >( 1.0 , 0.0 );

const double dt = 0.1;

typedef runge_kutta4< state_type , double , state_type , double ,
                      vector_space_algebra > stepper_type;

integrate_const( stepper_type() , stuart_landau( 2.0 , 1.0 ) , x , 0.0 , 10.0 , dt , streaming_observer( cout ) );
//]

return 0;
```

}

However this gives a plethora of errors.

Could anyone give me a minimum working example with complex ODEs? and even better implementing high precision data types..It looks like odeint can support quite arbitrary state types but I'm having a lot of trouble getting them to work.

**Updated code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>


extern "C" {
#include <quadmath.h>
}

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

//[ stuart_landau_system_function
typedef std::vector<std::complex < __float128 > > state_type;

struct stuart_landau
{
__float128 m_eta;
__float128 m_alpha;

stuart_landau( __float128 eta = 1.0L , __float128 alpha = 1.0L )
: m_eta( eta ) , m_alpha( alpha ) { }

void operator()( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t ) const
{
    const complex< __float128 > I( 0.0 , 1.0 ); //define complex I     

    dxdt[0] = x[1];
    dxdt[1] = ( 1.0 + m_eta * I ) * x[0] - ( 1.0 + m_alpha * I )*x[1];
}
};
//]




struct streaming_observer
{
 std::ostream& m_out;

streaming_observer( std::ostream &out ) : m_out( out ) { }

template < class State >
void operator()( const State &x , double t ) const
{
    m_out << t;
  /*  m_out << "\t" << x[0].real() << "\t" << x[0].imag() ;
    m_out << "\n";*/
 }
};




int main( int argc , char **argv )
{
//[ stuart_landau_integration
state_type x(2);
 x[0] = complex< __float128 >( 1.0L , 0.0L );
 x[1] = complex< __float128 >( 1.0L , 0.0L );

const double dt = 0.1;

typedef runge_kutta4< state_type, __float128 > stepper_type;

integrate_const( stepper_type() , stuart_landau( 2.0L , 1.0L ) , x , 0.0 , 10.0 , dt    
 /*, streaming_observer( cout ) */);
 //]

 return 0;
 }
```

**ERROR LOG ON COMPILE:**

```
vecPrec.cpp: In member function ‘void stuart_landau::operator()(const state_type&,    
state_type&, double) const’:
 vecPrec.cpp:33:35: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘1.0e+0 + std::operator* [with 
 _Tp = __float128]((* &((const stuart_landau*)this)->stuart_landau::m_eta), (* & I))’
 vecPrec.cpp:33:35: note: candidates are:
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:327:5: note: template<class _Iterator>    std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator> std::operator+(typename 

 std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type, const   std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2306:5: note: template<class _CharT, class  _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const    std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,   _Alloc>&)
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:694:5: note: template<class _CharT, class  _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const   _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
  /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:710:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(_CharT,     const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
  /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2343:5: note: template<class _CharT, class  _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const   std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2359:5: note: template<class _CharT, class   _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const   std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, _CharT)
  /usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:321:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp>  std::operator+(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:330:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp>  std::operator+(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const _Tp&)
    /usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:339:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp>  std::operator+(const _Tp&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:440:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp>  std::operator+(const std::complex<_Tp>&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:266:3: note: std::_Bit_iterator   std::operator+(std::ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_iterator&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:266:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::complex<__float128>’ to ‘const std::_Bit_iterator&’
    /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:352:3: note: std::_Bit_const_iterator std::operator+(std::ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_const_iterator&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:352:3: note:   no known conversion for   argument 2 from ‘std::complex<__float128>’ to ‘const std::_Bit_const_iterator&’
   vecPrec.cpp:33:66: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘1.0e+0 + std::operator*  [with _Tp = __float128]((* &((const stuart_landau*)this)->stuart_landau::m_alpha), (* &   I))’
  vecPrec.cpp:33:66: note: candidates are:
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:327:5: note: template<class _Iterator>   std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator> std::operator+(typename    std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2306:5: note: template<class _CharT, class     _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+   (const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const   std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
  /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:694:5: note: template<class _CharT, class   _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+  (const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:710:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+   (_CharT, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
    /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2343:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2359:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, _CharT)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:321:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp> std::operator+(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
    /usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:330:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp> std::operator+(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const _Tp&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:339:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp> std::operator+(const _Tp&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:440:5: note: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp> std::operator+(const std::complex<_Tp>&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:266:3: note: std::_Bit_iterator std::operator+(std::ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_iterator&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:266:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::complex<__float128>’ to ‘const std::_Bit_iterator&’
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:352:3: note: std::_Bit_const_iterator std::operator+(std::ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_const_iterator&)
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:352:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::complex<__float128>’ to ‘const std::_Bit_const_iterator&’
```

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly what you are asking for. If you want help resolving the "plethora of errors", you better include these in the question. If you are just asking for unspecified examples, that would be off topic here.

Comment: Well ideally I would just like some to modify one the simple example from the odeint website e.g. https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/master/libs/numeric/odeint/examples/stuart_landau.cpp to take a `vector<complex<__float128> >` as the state type. I feel like it should be very easily done and I can't understand why the simple exchanges I made above don't work. Even with the simpler state type of `vector <complex<double> >`.

Comment: To be honest I would be happy with any working example of odeint which could solve a system of two first order equations (i.e. state type is vector) and takes high precision complex numbers as elements. Whichever ODE is fine. To get the high precison complex libquadmath __float128 or _complex128, or boost.multiprecision maybe could be used? I'm not so fussed about resolving the above errors just getting a working minimal example of odeint, however simple, with these kinds of state types

Comment: The errors are all to do with the state type being changed, if you put things back to simple double they all go away.

Comment: added a small sample of the kind of thing. The page in the docs http://headmyshoulder.github.com/odeint-v2/doc/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/state_types__algebras_and_operations.html explains more about state types, setting up algebras and operations that seems to be source of these kind of errors, but for a vector of complex doubles I thought it would work out the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the above example to work you need to use the `range_algebra`. You are using the `vector_space_algebra` which expects more or less that for the `state_type` all operators +*-/ are defined. This is not the case for `std::vector<>`. Simply use

```
typedef runge_kutta4< state_type > stepper_type;
```

This typedef silenty uses the `range_algebra`.

For the other case try

```
typedef vector< complex< __float128 > > state_type;
typedef runge_kutta4< state_type , __float128 > stepper_type;
```

The precondition for the above two lines to work is that for __float128 the operators-*/+ are already defined.

Comment: thanks, so now I can use the vector of complex doubles. For the `__float128` the operators -*/+ are already defined in the sense that I can do `__float128 x=7.0; __float128 y=3.0; _float128 z=x*y` etc and then output z to screen,this is fine. One thing that is not defined is the `<<` operator, as this is a `C` type, you have to convert them to string with `quadmath_snprinf(...)` first.  Do I have to define the overloading of << or something? I've tried to just turn all outputs and observations off for now to bypass this.

Comment: Having said that upon compile, the errors I'm getting are things like `error: no match for 'operator+' ` so perhaps it doesn't even like the basic algebra operators..

Comment: I've updated my latest attempt at `__float128`.

Comment: It seems that the operators are not defined, or maybe they are not overloaded for combinations like double * __float128. Can you give me more error messages?

Comment: I can also do `double x=1; __float128 y=7.0L; z=x+y` and output z OK. so looks like such combos are OK. I will update the orig post with the error log file, one sec.

Comment: Could it be `<<` operator giving issues? If this is the case how do I fix? should I define some class to make my own type based on `__float128` then overload these operators myself?

Comment: It is uncomment, so there should be no problem with operator<<. Can you try to explicitly cast the constants in  stuart_landau::operator() to __float128, like __float128( 1.0 ), etc.

Comment: that fixed it! Why? I just need to work out a cleverer way to output these __float128's now.

Comment: Because the operators are not overload for operator+( double , __float128 ), operator+( __float128 , double ), etc.

Comment: thanks you've been a really great help to my project. Sorry to bore you with another question but if I wanted to use the boost.multiprecision (I've now downloaded and included the header etc) would I just replace _float128 everywhere with `boost::multiprecision:: something <50>`, say I wanted 50dp precision? which type would you recommend?

Comment: when I run the GMP `lorenz_gmpxx.cpp` exactly as is from the website there are errors about casting a gmp type to to type `size_t`. I have installed GMP and it's in my path, and I'm linking the libs `-lgmp -lgmpxx`. I haven't changed a thing from the orig source code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18668/discussion-between-headmyshoulder-and-fpghost)